# Set Tab Position in Tab View of Fragment from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have two `Tab` in my `Home` Fragment using [viewpager](/questions/tagged/viewpager).I am calling my `Home` Fragment when `ActivityTwo` is open.In Home Fragment I have one `FloatingButton` which when click I go to `Information` Fragment.When button is clicked in Information Fragment I am coming to `Home` Fragment and I need to open Second Tab.How to achieve this ?
This is code for setting TabView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_tab, container, false);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            tabLayout=(TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
            viewPager=(ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
             viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("One"));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Two"));
          PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
            //PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
```

This is code for replacing the `Home` Fragment

```
freeTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Confirmation.");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure to Free this Person?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        freeSinglePerson();
                        alertMsg.successMessage(infoTable,"Person Free Successfully.");
                        Home home=new Home();
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame,home);
                        vp.setCurrentItem(1);
                        tx.commitAllowingStateLoss();

                    }
                });
```

When my `Home` Fragment is replaced I want to set the Second Tab.How to achieve this ?

Comment: have u tried this  tabLayout.getTabAt(yourTabIndex).select();

Comment: How to get that TabLayout in that Fagment ?

Comment: from your tab layout activity

Comment: But I have set  my TabLayout in Fragment. So I am getting null ?

Comment: your tab layout inside Activity or Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to get tab layout from Activity

```
public TabLayout yourPublicMethodToGetTabLayout(){ // inside activity
 return tabLayout;
}
TabLayout tabview=    ((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethodToGetTabLayout(); //inside fragment
```

Then set tab position

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabview.getTabAt(yourTabIndex).select();
        }
}, 100);
```